# How to distinguish in quotes delimiter vs out of quotes delimiter

Tags: java, regex

I have a txt file that contains the following

```
SELECT TOP 20  personid AS "testQu;otes" 
FROM myTable
WHERE lname LIKE '%pi%' OR  lname LIKE '%m;i%';
SELECT TOP 10  personid AS "testQu;otes" 
FROM myTable2
WHERE lname LIKE '%ti%' OR  lname LIKE '%h;i%';
............
```

**The above query can be any legit SQl statement (on one or multiple lines , i.e. any way user wishes to type in )**

I need to split this txt and put into an array

```
File file ... blah blah blah
..........................
String myArray [] = text.split(";");
```

---

But this does not work properly because it take into account ALL `;` . I need to ignore those `;` that are within `";"` AND `';'`. For example `;` in here `'%h;i%'` does not count because it is inside `''`. How can I split correctly ?

Comment: Maybe you can simplify task for yourself? Do you expect ; only at the end of a line?

Comment: If that's not the case: Can you say something about the quoted strings, for example: Can they span multiple lines? Can there be escaped quotes within the strings? How are those quotes escaped? Can there be mixed quotes in a string?

Comment: They can span for multiple lines. They do not have to be at the end of the line. User can insert any legit `SQL` statement like this : `select * from mytable; select smth as "xxx" from table2 where somefield in ('x;xx', 'ccc;');` all in one line

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that each `;` you want to split on is at the end of line you can try to split on each `;` + line separator after it like

```
text.split(";"+System.lineSeparator())
```

If your file has other line separators then default ones you can try with

```
text.split(";\n")
text.split(";\r\n")
text.split(";\r")
```

BTW if you want to include `;` in split result (if you don't want to get rid of it) you can use [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) mechanism like

```
text.split("(?<=;)"+System.lineSeparator())
```

---

In case you are dynamically reading file line-by-line just check if `line.endsWith(";")`.

Answer (score 1):

I see a 'new line' after your ';' - It is generalizable to the whole text file ?
If you must/want use regular expression you could split with a regex of the form

```
;$
```

The $ means "end of line", depending of the regex implementation of Java (don't remember).

I will not use regex for this kind of task. Parsing the text and counting the number of ' or " to be able to recognize the reals ";" delimiters is sufficient.